# Legitimate question closed.

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This is a summary of the question :

Gives a file size and encryption method. Seeks information on how easy/difficult it is to crack, what kind of infrastructure is required and what are the best programming languages to write a program to crack this file.

Here is the link  : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27227/breaking-wikileaks-closed

Initially this question was down-voted 6 times and later closed as in-appropriate.

Why should a question that seems perfectly legitimate be dealt with in this fashion.

**Edit :** 
I have edited the question, I think most people had a problem with the wordings on the third point on the question to what I meant :

I read the guidelines of what is a good enough question. I am trying to figure out where the problem was with this question.
For Ref :

> inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.
>
> tend to have long, not short, answers.
>
> have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.
>
> invite sharing experiences over opinions.
>
> insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.
>
> are more than just mindless social fun.

I can understand if this question is not meant to be on programmers and should be on SO instead. But otherwise I fail to see where this question is not right. I just feel this question has been closed when it should have been left open.

Comment: I think, I'll go with the trend and get myself a new hobby. randomly down-vote questions and answers. But, unlike haters, I have a life, so, that's going to be a little difficult.

Comment: Community is saying something to you. I will say more clearly: I never met one single user here that down-vote randomly. You're talking like you're the owner of the truth and the other users are stalking you. You are going deeper to wrong way on every new post.

Comment: did you even read the [subjective guidelines](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice) before posting?  Can you name and describe at least 4 of the 6 points you believe your question fits?

Answer (score 7):

That question would be more appropriate on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Programmers is more for discussion on style, features, the programmers themselves, etc, than "how can I do this" questions. Also, it is not a political forum (not a forum at all!). Questions on conspiracies are definately off topic. I suspect the question may have been kept open had it not asked about other governments. The other questions may or may not have been appropriate; I wouldn't have closed it for them.

Also, the members that closed the question have been a part of this community nearly from its inception. I would consider any accusation against their motives for closing questions as "off topic" very suspect, since they had quite a hand in developing this site.

Comment: +1 - I voted to close the question because the sensationalism completely devalued any merits that it might have had otherwise.

Comment: @Tim Post : Do you suggest people should shy away from asking and answering questions that might remotely be interpreted as sensational by someone, even though the actual question may be very precise and requests for an objective fact based answer?

Comment: @DMin, kindly, point me to the possibility of an objective, fact based answer in the original incarnation of the question in question, and I will happily rescind my argument. Our concept of objective might differ, however, but that does not preclude our conversation as pointless :)

Comment: @DMin, I did vote to close your original question, so let us use that as a reference point. Once I cast a close vote, I cannot rescind it.